# FATAL EXCEPTION when I'm trying to get JSON from the link

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to get an JSON object with weather information from a link using API http://api.weatherstack.com/current?access_key=111111111111111&query=New%20York&Lang=en

But I'm getting the following error:
2021-02-11 21:30:07.099 28106-28106/com.app.forecastmvvm E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.app.forecastmvvm, PID: 28106
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.app.forecastmvvm.data.response.CurrentWeatherEntry.toString()' on a null object reference
at com.app.forecastmvvm.ui.weather.current.CurrentWeatherFragment$onActivityCreated$1.invokeSuspend(CurrentWeatherFragment.kt:42)

I know what is the NullPointerException. I think that my link is not building correctly. What's wrong with that?

```
const val API_KEY = "111111111111111"

//http://api.weatherstack.com/current?access_key=111111111111111&query=New%20York&Lang=en

interface ApixuWeatherApiService {

    @GET(value = "current")
    fun getCurrentWeather(
        @Query(value = "query") location: String,
        @Query(value = "lang") languageCode: String = "en"
    ): Deferred<CurrentWeatherResponse>

    companion object {
        operator fun invoke(): ApixuWeatherApiService {
            val requestInterceptor = Interceptor { chain ->

                val url = chain.request()
                    .url()
                    .newBuilder()
                    .addQueryParameter("access_key", API_KEY)
                    .build()
                val request = chain.request()
                    .newBuilder()
                    .url(url)
                    .build()

                return@Interceptor chain.proceed(request)
            }
            val okHttpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .addInterceptor(requestInterceptor)
                .build()

            return Retrofit.Builder()
                .client(okHttpClient)
                .baseUrl("https://api.weatherstack.com/")
                .addCallAdapterFactory(CoroutineCallAdapterFactory())
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build()
                .create(ApixuWeatherApiService::class.java)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: `Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.app.forecastmvvm.data.response.CurrentWeatherEntry.toString()' on a null object `

Comment: There can be two possible causes: 1) null response for the api request made due to internet failure or request timeout. 2) Incorrect design of CurrentWeatherEntry data class which will be used by gson for Json serialization.

Answer (score 0):

What the error says is that the `toString()` method on an object of type `CurrentWeatherEntry` has been called. Maybe you have a `println()` or other logging statement somewhere? The error says that wherever you call the print/log of the object `CurrentWeatherEntry`, that object is `null`.